# Python ActiveMQ: Is it possible to use pika client to work on ActiveMQ?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, activemq-classic, amqp, pika

As I know ActiveMQ supports the `amqp://` protocol, and now I want to connect the ActiveMQ instance within python.

Is it possible and good to use the `pika` package to get it? As I read the document of pika, it seemed it was design to be used with `RabbitMQ` only.

Or else, what protocol should I use is most proper for ActiveMQ on python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pika seems to support AMQP 0.9.x. ActiveMQ supports AMQP 1.0 - a different protocol.

So, what you need is a AMQP 1.0 client - or a STOMP client - or a MQTT client.

[QPid proton](https://qpid.apache.org/proton/) is a Python AMQP 1.0 client.

[Stomp.py](https://github.com/jasonrbriggs/stomp.py) is an alternative using Stomp.

Comment: Thank you for the guide!